# What method should I use to solve rational equations like this for a different quantity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, applications, rational-functions

With electronics, various characteristics of a device can often be described by solving one equation for different quantities. The problem that I run into a lot with my textbooks is that I can't figure out how they manipulate (most often) rational equations to do so.

For example, this equation describes the output sensitivity of a Wheatstone Bridge with variable resistances as a function of $\epsilon$:

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{\epsilon G(\nu+1)}{2-\epsilon G(\nu-1)}$$

If $G=2,\,\nu=0.3$, and $\epsilon=10^{-3}$, then the sensitivity is $1.3\;mV/V$.

The text then goes on to say that the equation can be used to determine the output per unit $\,\epsilon\,$ i.e., $\,V_o/\epsilon\,$, as a function of $\,V_i\,$ and that the result, given $G=2,\,\nu=0.3$, and $V_i=10$, is $13\;{\mu}V/\mu\epsilon$.

I tried whatever I could think of to arrive at an equation for $\,V_o/\epsilon\,$ in terms of $\,V_i\,$ but now I've pretty much resigned myself to computing it with a script.

Are there are any methods I can use to solve this equation (and equations like it) for $\,V_o/\epsilon\,$ or a different quantity by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to isolate $\epsilon$ on one side.

The trick is factoring $\epsilon$ out. It looks like this:

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{\epsilon G(\nu+1)}{2-\epsilon G(\nu-1)}$$

Multiply with the denominators, we get

$$V_o(2-\epsilon G(\nu-1)=V_i\epsilon G(\nu+1)$$

Now factor out the left-hand-side.

$$2V_o-V_o\epsilon (G\nu-1)=V_i\epsilon G(\nu+1)$$

Separate the $\epsilon$-terms from everything else:

$$2V_o=V_o\epsilon (G\nu-1)+V_i\epsilon G(\nu+1)$$

As I said now the "trick" is factoring $\epsilon$ out.
Then

$$2V_o=\epsilon(V_o G(\nu-1)+V_i G(\nu+1))$$

Now divide by $\epsilon$.

You get $$\frac{2V_o}{\epsilon}= V_o G(\nu-1)+V_i G(\nu+1)$$.

So this would be the standard method on solving equations like this for $\epsilon$, as you could isolate $\epsilon$ completly.

However I am unsure if I interpreted your question correctly, and what your textbook says.
It should not be possible, to write this equation into the form

$V_o/\epsilon=\dotso$ without having $V_o$ appearing on the right-hand-side of the equation.

Comment: Please let me know if this answers your question, or not.

Comment: I arrived at the same result and couldn't get it into a form without $V_o$ on the RHS. The equation highlighted in my post results from a system of three equations and involved some simplification so there might possibly be an alternate approach required from the outset. Or the authors of the text achieved the second result computationally as well. Anyway, that pretty much answers my question so thanks.